# Is parametric polymorphism the same as dispatching on arity?

Tags: types, programming-languages, type-theory

If parametric polymorphism is dispatching without depending on the types of the parameters then what else is there to dispatch upon other than the arity? If it isn't the same could someone provide a counter example?

Comment: Parametric polymorphism is not related to, or dependent on any form of dispatch. Why do you think so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Parametric Polymorphism

The idea behind parametric polymorphism is that you *don't* dispatch—a parametrically polymorphic function is one that *behaves in the same way* for all input types.  Let's consider a very simple example (I'm going to use Haskell<sup>1</sup>):

```hs
id x = x
```

This defines a function named `id` which takes one argument, `x`, and returns it.  This is the *id*entity function; it doesn't do anything.  Now, what type should `id` have?  It's definitely a function, so it will have the type `input -> output` for some `input` and `output`.  We could say that `id` has type `Int -> Int`; then `id 3` would evaluate to `3`, but `id True` wouldn't typecheck, which seems silly.  Saying `id :: Bool -> Bool` is no better; the problem is reversed.  We know that for `id`, it *doesn't matter* what type the input is; `id` ignores that structure and just passes the value around.  So for *any* type `a`, `id` has type `a -> a`, and we can write this explicitly:

```hs
id :: a -> a
id x = x
```

In Haskell, lowercase identifiers in types are are *universally quantified variables*—the above signature is the same as if I'd written `id :: forall a. a -> a`, except that writing the `forall` explicitly is only valid with some language extensions.

The identity function is the simplest example of a parametrically polymorphic function, and it highlights the idea that parametric functions simply pass data around.  They can't examine the data to do anything with it.

Let's consider a slightly more interesting function: list reversal.  In Haskell, lists of some type `a` are written `[a]`, so the `reverse` function is

```hs
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse []     = []
reverse (x:xs) = reverse xs ++ [x]
  -- `x:xs` is the list whose first element is `x` and whose second element is
  -- `xs`; `++` is the list-append operator.
```

The `reverse` function shuffles the elements of the list around, but it never manipulates them (and hence never "dispatches" on them).  Hence, `reverse` knows it must take and return lists of something—but it doesn't care what that something is.

One last example of parametric polymorphism is the `map` function.  This function takes a function `f` and a list, and applies that function to each element in the list.  This description tells us that we don't care about the input or output types of the function, and nor do we care about the type of the input list—but they must match up appropriately.  Thus, we have

```hs
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
  -- In Haskell, function application is whitespace, so `map f xs` is like
  -- `map(f,xs)` in a C-like language.
```

Note that the input (respectively output) type of the passed-in function and the type of the elements of the input (respectively output) list must match; however, the input and output types can be distinct from each other or not, we don't care.

### Parametric Polymorphism and Subtyping

You ask, in a comment, if parametric functions just accept values of the top type.  The answer is no: subtyping is completely independent of parametric polymorphism.  Haskell doesn't have any notion of subtyping at all: an `Int` is an `Int`, and a `Bool` is a `Bool`, and never the twain shall meet.  In Java, you have both generics and subtyping, but the two features are semantically unrelated (unless you use *bounded polymorphism* of the form `<T extends Super>`, but this is more like a form of *ad-hoc polymorphism*, which I discuss below).  Parametric polymorphism really is what it says: functions that accept *any* type.  This is not the same as functions that accept a top type and rely on subsumption/implicit upcasting.  One way to think about it is that parametric functions take an additional argument: the type of the parameter.  So instead of `id 3`, you would have `id Int 3`; instead of `id True`, you would have `id Bool True`.  In Haskell, you never need to do this explicitly, so there's no syntax for it.  On the other hand, in Java, you sometimes need to, and so there's syntax which reflects this, as in `Collections.<String>emptyList()`.

---

## Ad-hoc Polymorphism

Parametric polymorphism often contrasts with various forms of *ad-hoc polymorphism*: polymorphism that allows one function to behave in different ways at different types.  This is where "dispatch" shows up; where parametric polymorphism is about uniformity, ad-hoc polymorphism is about differences.  Sometimes you *don't* want a function to act the same way at every type!

Standard Java-like object-oriented subtype polymorphism, which is formally called *nominal subtyping*, is an example of this; in Java, for instance, the `boolean Object.equals(Object)` method uses subtype polymorphism to dispatch on its first argument and return the appropriate result.  It's clear that you wouldn't want equality to be parametric; you can't write one function that accurately compares both strings and integers for equality!  Note, however, that `.equals` also uses `instanceof` to perform a "typecase" check of the run-time type of the argument; the `int Object.hashCode()` method is an example of a purely subtype-polymorphic method.

Haskell uses a different approach, called *type-class polymorphism*, to handle this.  Here's a whirlwind tour of how that works.  First, we say what it means to be comparable for equality (note that Haskell lets you define function names which are arbitrary operators, and then use them infix):

```hs
class Eq a where -- To say that a type `a` is comparable for equality, implement
                 -- these functions:
  (==) :: a -> a -> Bool -- Equality
  (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool -- Inequality

  -- We can also define default implementations for those functions:
  x == y = not (x /= y)
  x /= y = not (x == y)
```

Then, we instantiate the type class; for instance, here we say how to compare booleans for equality.

```hs
instance Eq Bool where
  True  == True  = True
  False == False = True
  _     == _     = False
    -- `_` means "don't care".
```

And when we want to compare elements for equality, we specify that we must have a type which satisfies the appropriate constraint.  For instance, the `elem` function which checks if an element occurs in a list has type `Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`; we can read this as "for any `a` *which is an instance of `Eq`*, `elem` expects an `a` and a list of `a`s, and returns a boolean":

```hs
elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem _ []     = False
elem y (x:xs) = x == y || elem y xs
  -- Haskell supports an infix syntax that would have allowed us to write
  -- `y `elem` xs`, with the backticks around `elem`.
```

Here, the `elem` function is *not* parametrically polymorphic, because we have some information about the type `a`—we know that we can compare its elements for equality.  Consequently, `elem` will *not* behave in the same way for every input type (and there are some types we can't even compare for equality, such as functions), and so there's a form of type-based dispatch going on here, too.

---

<sup>1</sup> In case you're more familiar with languages like Java, the same function in Java would be (ignoring the containing class)

```
public static <T> T id(T t) { return t; }
```

Note that Java, unlike Haskell, allows you to violate parametricity by using the `instanceof` operator or calling methods like `.toString()` that are always available, but our `id` function doesn't do that.

Comment: One more question, If they don't 'dispatch', as in choose a function to apply from a variety of functions with the name same but different types on the parameters, at all do they just accept function that work on the Top Type (ie. t in the case of Common Lisp)?

Comment: PuercoPop: No, they don't just work on the top type; Haskell doesn't even have such a thing.  I added a paragraph to my answer clarifying this ("Parametric Polymorphism and Subtyping").

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. So apparently my confusion stemmed from the what was polymorphism referring to in the case of ad-hoc and parametric polymorphism. I was under the impression that it was called polymorphism because the function itself changed but apparently it is referring to working for different types of parameters. Is my new interpretation correct?

Comment: PuercoPop: Yep!  A polymorphic function works for different parameter types.  If it's parametric, it handles them in a uniform way; if it's ad-hoc, it can handle them in different ways.